# How to join 2 queries in SQL Server with value after sum

Tags: sql-server

I want to join 2 queries after sum column NUM_TM....

```
SELECT 
    CON_NO, EXP_DT, NTE_DR, DKD_ID
FROM 
    FILB01B
WHERE 
    NUM_TM = (SELECT MAX(NUM_TM) FROM FILB01B WHERE DKD_ID = 'BL') 
    AND DKD_ID = 'BL' 

UNION

SELECT 
    CON_NO, EXP_DT, NTE_DR, DKD_ID
FROM 
    FILB01B
WHERE 
    NUM_TM = (SELECT MAX(NUM_TM) FROM FILB01B WHERE DKD_ID = 'DC') 
    AND DKD_ID = 'DC' 

UNION

SELECT 
    CON_NO, EXP_DT, NTE_DR, DKD_ID
FROM 
    FILB01B
WHERE 
    NUM_TM = (SELECT MAX(NUM_TM) FROM FILB01B WHERE DKD_ID = 'TU' ) 
    AND DKD_ID = 'TU'
```

```
SELECT 
    DKD_ID, SUM(AMT_QT) AS AMT_QT 
FROM 
    FILB01B 
WHERE 
    DKD_ID ='BL' 
GROUP BY 
    DKD_ID 

UNION

SELECT 
    DKD_ID, SUM(AMT_QT) AS AMT_QT 
FROM 
    FILB01B 
WHERE 
    DKD_ID ='DC' 
GROUP BY 
    DKD_ID 

UNION

SELECT 
    DKD_ID, SUM(AMT_QT) AS AMT_QT 
FROM 
    FILB01B 
WHERE 
    DKD_ID = 'TU' 
GROUP BY 
    DKD_ID
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    
(
    SELECT CON_NO,EXP_DT,NTE_DR,DKD_ID
    FROM FILB01B
    WHERE NUM_TM = (SELECT MAX(NUM_TM) FROM FILB01B WHERE DKD_ID = 'BL') AND DKD_ID = 'BL' UNION
    SELECT CON_NO,EXP_DT,NTE_DR,DKD_ID
    FROM FILB01B
    WHERE NUM_TM = (SELECT MAX(NUM_TM) FROM FILB01B WHERE DKD_ID = 'DC') AND DKD_ID = 'DC' UNION
    SELECT CON_NO,EXP_DT,NTE_DR,DKD_ID
    FROM FILB01B
    WHERE NUM_TM = (SELECT MAX(NUM_TM) FROM FILB01B WHERE DKD_ID = 'TU' ) AND DKD_ID = 'TU'
) a
    inner join 
        (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    
            (
                SELECT DKD_ID,SUM(AMT_QT) AS AMT_QT FROM FILB01B WHERE DKD_ID ='BL' GROUP BY DKD_ID UNION
                SELECT DKD_ID,SUM(AMT_QT)AS AMT_QT FROM FILB01B WHERE DKD_ID ='DC' GROUP BY DKD_ID UNION
                SELECT DKD_ID,SUM(AMT_QT)AS AMT_QT FROM FILB01B WHERE DKD_ID ='TU' GROUP BY DKD_ID
            ) b
        ) b
        on a.YourKey = b.YourKey
```